# Как по LogCat найти реальную строку в исходном коде, в которой произошла ошибка?

Tags: android, android-studio, отладка

**LogCat** указывает номер строки (строка 2793) в которой произошла ошибка, но в исходнике нет такой строки!

Как грамотно ориентироваться по **LogCat** и находить в исходном коде реальную строку с ошибкой?

P.S. Этот **LogCat** взят из **Отчета о тестировании** из **Google Play Console** (тестирование происходит на сервере Google Play, на локальном компьютере все норм)

```
    ...
    FATAL EXCEPTION: ControllerMessenger
    Process: ..., PID: 11569
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{ru.../ru...Module1}: java.lang.NullPointerException: 
Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.String.contains(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
     at ndroid.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2793)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2864)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
     ...
```

Comment: У вас, кажется, cтандартный NPE. о конкретная строка должна быть выделена в логах синим цветом и она кликабельна.

Comment: Увы, это LogCat из Отчета о тестировании из Google Play Console

Comment: Ну... Если это весь лог, который есть, то остаётся только попробовать симулировать окружение, в коем падение было. Т.е. взять ту же версию ОС, ту же локаль, тот же девайс, запустить и попробовать воспроизвести.

Comment: В исходниках Андроида Вы свою ошибку по-любому не найдёте. Если это не весь стектрейс, то смотрите ниже, пока не увидите имя своего класса.

Comment: ЮрийСПБ спасибо!... А может можно с пом. каких-нибудь отладочных печатей это место повычислять? Я понял, что ошибка в строке с: .contains(... Но у меня таких мест несколько!!!

Comment: Если в логе этой информации нет, то кроме как вручную пытаться воспроизвести ничего сделать нельзя.